# Select a directory in a ListBox and display that selected directorie's files in another ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-web-developer-2010

I enumerated directories into a `ListBox` using this:

```
private void TE_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {            
IEnumerable<string> file = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var f in file)
        {
            lbz.Items.Add(String.Format(f));
        }
    }
```

Now, the `ListBox` displays all the directories in that given path, then I use:

```
private void lbz_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbz.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(lbz.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles() //:<------
                for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i) 
                {
                    lbz2.Items.Add(i); 
                }

            }
            else
            {
                tb1.Text = "Directory Doesn't Exist On This Path";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tb1.Text = "No Directory Selected";
        }

    }
```

The arrow is where I'm stumped, since I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer I can't use `GetFiles`, I have to use Enumerate.

I want to be able to populate another `ListBox` (lbz2) by selecting a directory in lbz and having that directories contents, all the files in it, displayed in lbz2.

If:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles() //:<------
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i) 
{
    lbz2.Items.Add(i); 
}
```

doesn't work, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(lbz.SelectedItem.ToString()))
{
    lbz2.Items.Add(filePath); 
}
```

EnumerateFiles returns `IEnumerable<string>`, not `string[]`.

Comment: It works, I had to remove "string[] filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles() //:<------ for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)" and add the "foreach" it works wonderfully, thank you. =)